# What would make a good dog/wolf foot in mountanous terrain?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, fauna, mountains

What characteristics (compare those of a mountain goat foot: good grip on rocks, doesn't slip off, etc) would the foot of a dog or a wolf need to have to be useful in rocky settings such as mountains (but not very steep ones) and rocky deserts? What about the pads, claws, general roughness?

This creature relies on chasing its prey, rather than being an ambush predator.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Krakukan, and welcome to Worldbuilding SE and Stack Exchange! I rewrote your question mainly for language. I think I got it all right, but if you feel my edit changed your intent in any way, by all means do feel free to [Edit] further.

Comment: How is this "unclear what you're asking"? Seems clear enough to me, even in [revision 1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/revisions/118139/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit Michael. Now it sounds much better

Comment: You're welcome Krakukan. Glad I could help. I hope you'll get some good answers.

Comment: Wolves do actually live in the mountains with their regular feet, and their areals have always included mountains. Their close relatives the coyotes and the jackals live in semi-deserts, and they have always lived in semi-deserts. (No large predators live in outright deserts.)

Comment: @AlexP: Not to mention that fairly ordinary dogs do quite well in mountain areas.  Mine's quite capable of chasing (and sometimes catching) squirrels, jackrabbits, bears, &c.  Though I do wish he'd stop with the bears :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mountain Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_dog) breeds are typically working dogs - built and adapted for protection of flocks. So I don't think they are a good reference point for your needs (a predator who chases its prey).

The species which would make a better reference point for a "prey-chasing rock dweller" I think is the snow leopard. Although it would prefer to ambush, it certainly [does chase prey across rocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj0EVT-Ekog).

[Some of their adaptations](http://www.discoverwildlife.com/animals/mammals/6-ways-snow-leopards-are-adapted-their-habitat). Specifically - large paws, short forelimbs and a long thick tail, all to help balance. Also - extremely powerful rear legs - ability to leap crevices etc is crucial for navigating rocky environments.

They also have [thick paws](http://snowleopardadaptations.weebly.com/adaptations.html) to avoid cutting themselves easily on sharp rocks.